# How to get the input value after submitting the form in jsf ?

Tags: jsf

I hava an inputText and a command button

```
 <div id="address">
 <div class="label">Address<span>*</span></div>
      <div class="detail">
           <h:inputText class="text" value="#{restaurant.address}" />
           <h:commandButton id="add" value="Add" action="#{restaurant.submitInfo}"/>
      </div>
```

First, `restaurant.address` is `null`, when i click the "Add" button, the value of `restaurant.address` becomes a `string`. So how can i show its value in `inputText` tag after submitting the form ? Thank you!

Comment: Where you need to show the value of the address, in the same or in another `<h:inputText>`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `<f:ajax>` tag is powerful for this, by adding an identifier for your `<h:inputText />` and nesting the new tag into `<h:commandButton>` opening and closing tags :

```
<div id="address">
     <div class="label">Address<span>*</span></div>
     <div class="detail">
           <h:inputText id="address" class="text" value="#{restaurant.address}" />
           <h:commandButton id="add" value="Add" action="#{restaurant.submitInfo}">
                 <f:ajax render="address" execute="address" />
           </h:commandButton>
     </div>
```

Comment: If that isn't a button , it's a diffirent inputText, when i fill in it, how can i do to that string showed in inputText address>

Comment: you mean you have two `<h:inputText >` tags with no button ?

Comment: What's the meaning of ajaxify the submission and rendering of **the same component**? At least do it in another component like `<h:outputText>` or, as OP asks, in another `<h:inputText>`.

Comment: @DoThanhTung please be more careful when accepting an answer. This answer doesn't solve your problem nor will help future readers.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, the OP was asking about 1 button and 1 inputText, then he asked for another else. Where's the problem ?

Comment: I ask you: what's the entire purpose to use ajax to render the same component you're processing? It's like edit component A and update A to show that A is working (when already works), at least update a component B. Looks like you haven't even understood OP's question (which is also very odd).

Comment: This is up to the OP's needs, i don't know, maybe he's trying to learn/test something, or to learn a process step by step as he's doing right now. What i did, is just answered him depending in his understood question. I understood what you said Mr @LuiggiMendoza, that's a real purpose for an ajax's use and i should next time to indicate to it to provide a complete answer, thanks for the remark.

Comment: Note that if OP has two components inside the same form bounded to the same managed bean field e.g. `value="#{restaurant.address}"` then this approach won't do.

Comment: Unless we use `event` attribute.

Comment: Thank @Omar I can do it with that button, now i want test with other situations Which are not button . Can you help me?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Omar's answer is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @Omar Can you tell me how i should do if that is not button, it only is an event. Thank you

Comment: At that time, you should use the event handlers like `valueChangeListener`, `actionListener`, etc. The new situation is 2 `<h:inputText>` with one event ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using ajax to update an the input component. See [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_ajax.htm) to know how to use `f:ajax` tag.